# WSO2 EMM Remove Device/user from list

Tags: android, mdm

I've searched lot but I cannot find the resolution - if I enroll device to user and then wipe the device how to:

- remove user (Error is: User cannot be deleted, this user has enrolled device) -  I've found i can delete user via Carbon interface but device is untouched.
- remove device (give the device to different user) - if i create new user - new entry with same device in interface will be shown

"`explanation`": 
I have created one user in WSO2 EMM and then I've enrolled the device to this user, device is registering fine -  I can do everything what android agent can. In next step this user will be deleted. It will be impossible in EMM management console - web error will be shown ("..user has enrolled device" - as earlier)

My question is about procedure to remove user and device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform an "Enterprise Wipe" on the user's device first. Head over to "Device Management", select the user's device and click on the "Enterprise Wipe" operation.

Once the operation has been successfully pushed onto the device, it is removed from the server automatically. Once the user is unassigned from all devices (if he has multiple devices), he/she can now be removed from the system with no errors/warnings.